# CSS Div sliding up doesn't take contents with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have code this code

```html
   <div id='cart_top' class='cart_parts'>
    <dt class='list-item' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
     View your Quote
    </dt>
    <dd class='list-item'>
     <div id='triangle-up' class='side-by-side' style='float: right; margin-right: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 15px;' onClick='hider2()'>
    </div>
    </dd>
   </div>
   <div id='cart_body' class='cart_parts slider2 closed'>
     Lorem Ipsum fnrjnfirmfowmciodmckwmcporcpoiermcoimiocm
              kflkwremflkrwemfklwremfklewrmfklewrmfc
              foenfoeoifcfwoicnweiocmnwecmwilmccmkldsscml
   </div>
  <style> 
.side-by-side{
 display: inline-block;
 }

 #triangle-up { width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;  
 border-top: 10px solid black; 
 opacity:  0.6;}

 slider2{
 overflow-y: hidden;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration:.5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
 }
 .slider2.closed{
 max-height: 0;
 }


 .cart_parts{
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #cart_top{
 height: 40px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 background-color: #DADCD3;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
 }
 #cart_body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color:  red;
 }
  </style>
  <script>
hider2=function(){
  cart_bod=document.getElementById('cart_body');
  cart_bod.classList.toggle('closed');
 };
  </script>
```

................................

#edit: I have inserted the code here as asked for, however, as you can see, the code is a bit messed up. The dropdown overhangs to the left but the functionality is the same.

My problem is this:

When I click the down arrow, the div opens and closes like normal: the border and background color toggle like normal. The problem IS: while the div(cart_body), border and background toggle normally, the contained text of the div (cart_body)stays in place, no matter whether it is toggled on or off. I want the text inside the div(cart_body) to toggle with the rest of the div instead of staying visible. Anybody know what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code here...

Comment: @WhiteHat I provided a link to it. That is perfectly acceptable. Plenty of other answers do it. Don't try and impose your preference on my question. Doing it at liveweave instead of here gives me much more flexibility.

Comment: That isn't _"perfectly acceptable"_. Read the help section... "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "

Comment: see "Help others reproduce the problem" @ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, just wanted to help...

Comment: @Lal LiveWeave is for all intents and purposes the same thing as JSFiddle. I just happen to like it more. They serve the exact same purpose, and are pretty much the same thing. Try clicking the link before complaining about it.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon It should be noted that StackOverflow actively discourages posting only a link to a demo (could be JSFiddle, could be LiveWeave, etc.) without code in the original question. This was such a rampant problem that users are no longer able to post a question that links to a JSFiddle but has no code. Please don't do the same with LiveWeave.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon the problem isn't with LIveWeave - you're right, that is totally a helpful tool and a GOOD addition to your question.  The issue is that you haven't provided code in the actual question as well.  In the future, that Weave may disappear, and future readers of this post will have no idea what your question is actually about.  You need to post the code; LiveWeave (or JSFiddle) are helpful, but optional, add-ons.

Comment: You need to understand that solving problems for the question owners is only **one**, and not even the **main** purpose of SO. Its main purpose from my understanding is to provide a comprehensive archive of questions/answers related to programming. A question that only involves code via a link serves this main purpose way worse than if code is included. Also, codeweaver might at any point in the future become unavailable, this would render this question - and the answers - useless.

Comment: @Serlite  I wouldve been happy to post it here, but I opted to post it at liveweave because when I tried it with the "insert code snippet" here, it messed up the formatting, and I figured that potential answer writers would much rather see it the way it was intended to be.

Comment: Had I only seen the css here, there wouldn't have been any need for a working demo since the error is so obvious.

Comment: @connexo well, I clearly DIDN'T see the error here, as I was asking a question about it, so I included the whole thing so y'all could see all the code that contributed to the problem, because I didn't know which area was the problem. If I HAD, then I wouldn't have asked a question about it, would I have?

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon: In regards to code formatting, all you need to do is make sure that your code is indented by four spaces on each starting line. You can do that manually, or highlight it and press the `{}` button, or `Ctrl+K`. The code formatting tools work well if you give them a fair chance. If you're still having trouble, review the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ that isn't the problem. The problem was with the way it was rendering it. For the insert HTML or whatever that lets you run a snippet, when I put my code in, it rendered funny. That's why I used liveweave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.` in front of your css selector for `.slider2`, so your styles are not applied. Specifically, this means that there is no `overflow-y: hidden;` on your element, so assigning `max-height: 0;` just makes the text overflow the container. That's why you see the red `background-color` vanish, but not the text.

Comment: thanks. Simple error that I missed because the file that im writing that this comes from contains almost a thousand lines and I just missed it.

Comment: No problem. The valuable part of this is what you can learn from the comments on your question.